# contenteditable div, hide html tags on load?

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a div with `contenteditable='true'`. I also has some javascript that moves the content from this div to a hidden textarea and saves it to a database.

When I load the page I obviously want to do it backwards, load some html from the textarea to the contenteditable div. I can do that but now all the html tags like `<b>` becomes visible. I used `document.execCommand("bold", false, null);` before to make som bolded text by input to the div, but how can I load this text again and view it as bold?

```
jQuery("textarea:visible").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).textJq();
});

$.fn.textJq = function() {
    this.after("<div class='textJq-wrapper'></div>");
    var textarea = this;
    var wrapper = this.next();
    wrapper.append("<div class='textJq-header'></div>");
    var header = wrapper.children().first();
    wrapper.append("<div contenteditable='true' class='textJq-text'></div>");
    var viewer = header.next();

    $('.textJq-text').css({'height' : this.height(), 'width': '100%'});
    this.hide();

    // Init Tools
    header.append("<a href='#' class='textJq-bold'>B</a>");


    // Functions for each tool
    $(header).find('.textJq-bold').click(function() {
        document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
        return false;
    });

    // Update textarea on input
    $(viewer).on("input", function() {
        $(textarea).html($(viewer).html());
    });

    // Init text on load
    $(viewer).html($(textarea).html());
};
```

Comment: Updated with the jQuery script!

Comment: Use `val()` rather than `.html()` to get the value of a textarea. Even better, just use `textarea.value`.

Comment: For some reason that did not work the first time I tried, but it did now! That solved my problem!

Comment: Perhaps Tim Down should write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()` rather than `html()` to get the value of a textarea. Even better in this case, just use `textarea.value`.